# How to indicate to a user that an image/emoji is clickable

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, hyperlinks, click

I'm building an app where a user goes by an emoji.. that is their "profile name" so to speak. The problem I'm having is that it's not very intuitive that you can tap on a users emoji to get their profile page.

Usually with a name or username it's normal to tap on their name to view more about them, but with an image/emoji, I don't think it is...

This is how my layout currently looks:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFiiTd.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Is there a way to indicate to the user that they can in fact tap the icon/emoji to see more? Once someone knows they'll know forever, but I'm not sure it's intuitive in the beginning.. is it?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Question Jane,  I read through some NielsenNorman Guidance at this link... https://www.nngroup.com/articles/clickable-elements/ ...and there was some good info there.  That said, it sounds like you are wanting a little stronger hinting to your users that the emoji itself is clickable.

I'm not sure how grand a solution you desire. You could add a slight animation to the emoji, maybe a glow behavior, or slight movement.  Nothing drastic. I'd also add a hover tooltip on the emoji, that informs the user to click to view a profile. Its important that this animation is very slight as to not become intrusive or irritating to the user.

A really nice feature would be to recognize that the user has hovered or clicked the emoji previously, and to not display the animation/hint anymore.  This allows that assisted initial discovery, without future irritation.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. It's a mobile app, which means that hovering and tooltips don't really work, unfortunately. I do like your idea of animating the image... maybe if a user looks at a post for 3-5 seconds the emoji starts to bounce up and down very subtly.. It's not really something a user will want to tap on regularly though, maybe 10-15% of the time.

Comment: Srry I overlooked the mobile aspect!  And agree! Once they have tapped it, the animation will most likely not be needed again....